# Custom icon for .pkg file on Lion OSX

Tags: macos, icons, osx-lion, pkg-resources

I have created a package using PackageMaker and want to change the default icon for .pkg file.
After some googling, seticon utility from here http://sveinbjorn.org/osxutils_docs solved my problem for all OSX-es except the latest Lion 10.7 (Kernel 11.0.0). The default icon was replaced by grey square insensitive for double clicks, looks like broken file association.

Additional two days googling gave me some knowledge about resource fork, SetFile(1) and some other useful staff like this old thread [Changing icon of package created by package maker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2963855/changing-icon-of-package-created-by-package-maker) but still no luck.

I am trying to do something like:

> target=pack.pkg
>
> icon_filename="$(perl -e 'print "Icon\r"')"
>
> touch "$target/..namedfork/rsrc/$icon_filename"
>
> cp "Icon.icns" "$target/..namedfork/rsrc/$icon_filename"
>
> /Developer/Tools/SetFile -a C "$target"

and getting:
build-Mac:pack.pkg/..namedfork/ not a directory.

What am I doing wrong? Does anyone can tell me the difference in resource fork in Lion? Any other script-able solution?

Please note, I am a total newbie in MACs and will appreciate a detailed answer for dummies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally figured out it, in case of someone need it, putting it here. I used apple script:

```
set newIcon to (POSIX file "IconMac.icns") as alias
set theItem to (POSIX file "Installer.pkg") as alias

tell application "Preview"
activate
open newIcon
end tell
tell application "System Events"
tell process "Preview"
    keystroke "c" using command down
end tell
end tell
tell application "Preview" to quit

tell application "Finder"
set infoWindow to open information window of theItem
set infoWindowName to name of infoWindow
end tell

tell application "System Events"
tell application process "Finder"
    tell window infoWindowName
        keystroke tab
        delay 1
        keystroke "v" using command down
    end tell
end tell
end tell

tell application "Finder"
close infoWindow
end tell
```

Comment: This approach is not working on macOS 10.13.6. I was able to make it work for Mojave though by adding osascript to the Settings / Privacy / A11Y apps.

Comment: @gamma The script is not working for me on Mojave. Did you have to modify it at all from above? I'm getting permission denied from `com.apple.Preview/com.apple.Preview.PasteboardItems`

Comment: I think I left the script as it was. But I had to add the osascript command to Preferences / Privacy / A11Y Apps if I remember correctly.